# ajuda com nativeQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

Eu tentei fazer a query uasndo expression constructors e jpql , mas o jpql não eceita subqueryes e estou , então tentando fazer com nativeQuery . É possivel?

Estou recebendo mensagem de erro. Alguém saberia porquê?

A query é a seguinte :

```
StringBuilder jpql = new StringBuilder();
        jpql.append("select a2.codigoProduto , a2.descricao, a2.quantidade_recente, Soma ,a2.valor, a2.valor * Soma from")
                .append("(select p.codigoProduto,  sum(p.quantidade_recente) Soma   from Produto p ,Usuario u ")
                .append("where u.codigo = p.codigo_filial and u.codigo_chefe = 3  ) as a1,")
                .append(" (SELECT p1.codigoProduto, p1.descricao, p1.quantidade_recente , p1.valor from Produto aS p1,  Usuario u ")
                .append("where u.codigo = p1.codigo_filial and u.codigo_chefe = 3 ) as a2 ")
                .append("where a2.codigoProduto = a1.codigoProduto");

        // metodo buscarPorPaginacao
        Query query = manager.createNativeQuery(jpql.toString(), Filtro.class);
        // query.setParameter("codigo", 3L);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Filtro> resultado = query.getResultList();
        for (Filtro prod : resultado) {
            System.out.println(" Impressão Filtro da Empresa: ");
            System.out.println(" CodigoProduto : " + prod.getCodigoProduto() + " Produto " + prod.getDescricao()
                    + " Quantidade " + prod.getQuantidade() + " Total " + prod.getSoma() + " Receita " + prod.getReceita() );

        }
```

A query que sai no console é a seguinte :

```
 select
    a2.codigoProduto ,
    a2.descricao,
    a2.quantidade_recente,
    Soma ,
    a2.valor,
    a2.valor * Soma 
from
    (select
        p.codigoProduto,
        sum(p.quantidade_recente) Soma   
    from
        Produto p ,
        Usuario u 
    where
        u.codigo = p.codigo_filial 
        and u.codigo_chefe = 3  ) as a1,
    (SELECT
        p1.codigoProduto,
        p1.descricao,
        p1.quantidade_recente ,
        p1.valor 
    from
        Produto aS p1,
        Usuario u 
    where
        u.codigo = p1.codigo_filial 
        and u.codigo_chefe = 3 ) as a2 
where
    a2.codigoProduto = a1.codigoProduto
```

Ela é executada no mysql e retorna resultados corretamente , mas na classe que estou testando ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'codigo' not found.
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:870)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1064)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getLong(ResultSetImpl.java:2743)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getLong(NewProxyResultSet.java:2478)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:74)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:267)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:263)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:338)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:785)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:721)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:953)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
... 10 more
```

Comment: Então, se você copiar a query do console e executa-la no MySQL ela funciona perfeitamente? Porque no console diz que a coluna código não existe no banco. Deve ser a 'u.codigo' da subquery.

Comment: também pensei assim tirei o u.codigo, mas a mensagem de erro continua

Comment: Complicado então. Tente rodar apenas o select principal. Se passar, adicione a primeira subquery e assim por diante. Talvez consiga assim, identificar onde exatamente pode estar o problema.

Comment: Seria melhor fazer com Criteria?

Comment: Não sei dizer, depende do seu conhecimento com Criteria.

Answer (score -2):

O problema ocorre, pois a entidade **Filtro** está esperando o campo codigo. Como este campo não é localizado no resultado da consulta é apresentando esta mensagem. Caso está consulta não possa ser alterada, sugiro a criação de um POJO para solução do problema. Assim sendo, o código ficaria semelhante a isso:

```
Query query = manager.createNativeQuery(jpql.toString(), PojoCriado.class);
```

Caso não tenha entendido a resposta, sugiro que  poste a entidade Filtro. :)